# What is the best method for determining if an ID is in a set without storing the entire set?

Tags: cryptography, passwords, embedded, compression, storage

I have a storage-limited application where it must be verified if an ID is in a set or not. It's expected that the total set of IDs will be 1k's to 10k's of IDs, which is cumbersome to store, and will create too much traffic upstream to verify IDs individually with the master database.

Without having access to the entire set, is there an algorithm that will allow the application to verify if an ID is in the set? It is feasible to perform more extensive calculations remotely before storing data on the application hardware if that helps to reduce the storage required.

I have limited experience in data algorithms, but I am envisioning some function where our domain of approved IDs has a single value (or limited range of values) output that we can store on the application hardware. On the other hand, IDs outside approved IDs will not overlap with this output range, at least with reasonable certainty. The function would need to work with arbitrary ID values, as they may need to be activated/deactivated in the future.

Is something like this at all possible? Does there exist a data algorithm that would be useful for this case?

Comment: There are possibilities; the 64 bit ID might be constructed with certain mathematical properties that can be verified remotely, perhaps cryptography can play a role. For example, a larger ID, say 256 bits, can be created and signed on the server using a private key and thereafter the signature can be verified by your software using a hard-coded public key. If the signature is verified then the ID is "in the set". The possibilities are endless and there is very little detail in this question to say much more.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Appreciate the response. I apologize if I'm unclear/imprecise with my question (this is not an area where I have much experience), so let me know if I can add any specifics to help you or others answer the question. Your solution sounds interesting, is there a name for this method so that I can do some further research? I'm aware of public/private key encryption, but not not knowledgeable enough to quite understand how it could be used in our application.

Comment: If the set is prone to change or shrinkage then I suppose the problem is pretty tough. If not then you could just add a MAC at the end of the ID using a key and verify it on receipt with the same key.